# NHibernate Joining on non-mapped property

Tags: nhibernate, join, subquery

I have two classes SystemInvitation and User.  User has a property called Email and SystemInvitation has a property called InviteesEmailAddress.  There is no relationship in the domain between these properties.

Is it possible using the Criteria API to produce a query like:

select
    si.InviteesEmailAddress
    , si.Identifier
    , case when u.id is null then 0 else 1 end as UserExists 
from 
    SystemInvitation si
    left outer join [User] u on u.Email = si.InviteesEmailAddress

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should map the InviteesEmailAddress column in the mapping for SystemInvitation using something like this:

```
<many-to-one name="InviteesEmailAddress" fetch="join" class="User"
    column="Email" cascade="none" not-found="ignore" />
```